# How to fix 'Cannot deploy app on heroku'?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, cmd

I am trying to deploy ruby on rails application on heroku via cmd prompt the issue and error is displayed in the logs. It is giving application error.I am getting application error when I do `heroku open` on the command prompt window.How shall I solve this error. I also tried removing the issues related to the console on the localhost:3000

```
   C:\r5.1>heroku logs --tail
    2019-11-11T14:16:38.867063+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
    2019-11-11T14:16:43.692688+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 19801 -e production`
    2019-11-11T14:16:46.394640+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
    2019-11-11T14:16:46.381024+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
    2019-11-11T14:16:46.254086+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/bin/env: ‘ruby\r’: No such file or directory
    2019-11-11T20:00:49.460823+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
    2019-11-11T20:00:59.165978+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 29263 -e production`
    2019-11-11T20:01:04.157480+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
    2019-11-11T20:01:04.118816+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
    2019-11-11T20:01:03.964097+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/bin/env: ‘ruby\r’: No such file or directory
    2019-11-12T01:38:25.327629+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
    2019-11-12T01:38:29.528475+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 54505 -e production`
    2019-11-12T01:38:31.443429+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
    2019-11-12T01:38:31.413452+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
    2019-11-12T01:38:31.355207+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/bin/env: ‘ruby\r’: No such file or directory
    2019-11-12T04:43:24.305277+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=obscure-beyond-78036.herokuapp.com request_id=c969b84f-8226-4b14-a7a7-0dcd2f1a7ecf fwd="73.244.194.180" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
    2019-11-12T04:43:24.966438+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=obscure-beyond-78036.herokuapp.com request_id=98e6030c-5a7d-45b8-9463-b20378089873 fwd="73.244.194.180" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
    2019-11-12T04:45:44.551206+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=obscure-beyond-78036.herokuapp.com request_id=c38f043e-1c13-4227-a0ee-926e96031e96 fwd="73.244.194.180" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
    2019-11-12T04:45:44.724247+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=obscure-beyond-78036.herokuapp.com request_id=ca487a9b-815c-4198-881e-c1536624dcf0 fwd="73.244.194.180" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
    2019-11-12T07:14:57.497429+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
    2019-11-12T07:15:01.920946+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 19445 -e production`
    2019-11-12T07:15:04.382826+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
    2019-11-12T07:15:04.358062+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
    2019-11-12T07:15:04.270979+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/bin/env: ‘ruby\r’: No such file or directory
    2019-11-12T12:59:29.922938+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
    2019-11-12T12:59:34.199590+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 8495 -e production`
    2019-11-12T12:59:36.058436+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
    2019-11-12T12:59:36.011599+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/bin/env: ‘ruby\r’: No such file or directory
    2019-11-12T12:59:36.058915+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
    2019-11-12T18:57:44.195820+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
    2019-11-12T18:57:49.089790+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 55812 -e production`
    2019-11-12T18:57:50.902911+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
    2019-11-12T18:57:50.891004+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
    2019-11-12T18:57:50.829746+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/bin/env: ‘ruby\r’: No such file or directory
    2019-11-13T00:18:03.832712+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
    2019-11-13T00:18:11.709422+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 57129 -e production`
    2019-11-13T00:18:14.447216+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
    2019-11-13T00:18:14.426285+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
    2019-11-13T00:18:14.353062+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/bin/env: ‘ruby\r’: No such file or directory
    2019-11-13T06:18:16.247724+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
    2019-11-13T06:18:21.126039+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 56369 -e production`
    2019-11-13T06:18:23.030770+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
    2019-11-13T06:18:23.010262+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
    2019-11-13T06:18:22.964777+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/bin/env: ‘ruby\r’: No such file or directory
    2019-11-13T11:54:35.587058+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
    2019-11-13T11:54:43.164128+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 23216 -e production`
    2019-11-13T11:54:45.221161+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
    2019-11-13T11:54:45.054350+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/bin/env: ‘ruby\r’: No such file or directory
    2019-11-13T11:54:45.198218+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
    2019-11-13T17:32:52.968441+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
    2019-11-13T17:32:57.483433+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 41627 -e production`
    2019-11-13T17:32:59.635352+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
    2019-11-13T17:32:59.617603+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
    2019-11-13T17:32:59.529956+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/bin/env: ‘ruby\r’: No such file or directory
    2019-11-13T23:28:20.391491+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
    2019-11-13T23:28:25.383782+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 35541 -e production`
    2019-11-13T23:28:26.768967+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
    2019-11-13T23:28:26.746187+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
    2019-11-13T23:28:26.710575+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/bin/env: ‘ruby\r’: No such file or directory
    2019-11-14T05:20:57.113772+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
    2019-11-14T05:21:02.360484+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 39866 -e production`
    2019-11-14T05:21:04.955264+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
    2019-11-14T05:21:04.936109+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
    2019-11-14T05:21:04.867542+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/bin/env: ‘ruby\r’: No such file or directory
    2019-11-14T11:13:33.210556+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
    2019-11-14T11:13:37.194569+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 54606 -e production`
    2019-11-14T11:13:39.024888+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
    2019-11-14T11:13:39.010502+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
    2019-11-14T11:13:38.967553+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/bin/env: ‘ruby\r’: No such file or directory
    2019-11-14T16:42:11.985194+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
    2019-11-14T16:42:16.369127+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 6489 -e production`
    2019-11-14T16:42:18.158327+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
    2019-11-14T16:42:18.141167+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
    2019-11-14T16:42:18.091900+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/bin/env: ‘ruby\r’: No such file or directory
    2019-11-14T22:23:09.123597+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
    2019-11-14T22:23:13.156309+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 41127 -e production`
    2019-11-14T22:23:14.623692+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
    2019-11-14T22:23:14.542462+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/bin/env: ‘ruby\r’: No such file or directory
    2019-11-14T22:23:14.601341+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
    2019-11-15T04:07:18.215176+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
    2019-11-15T04:07:24.144091+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 28727 -e production`
    2019-11-15T04:07:26.088778+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
    2019-11-15T04:07:26.073282+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
    2019-11-15T04:07:26.028957+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/bin/env: ‘ruby\r’: No such file or directory
    2019-11-15T09:51:30.015825+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
    2019-11-15T09:51:35.432940+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 35443 -e production`
    2019-11-15T09:51:38.061514+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
    2019-11-15T09:51:38.042995+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
    2019-11-15T09:51:37.986622+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/bin/env: ‘ruby\r’: No such file or directory
    2019-11-15T15:32:36.641076+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
    2019-11-15T15:32:43.318738+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 50057 -e production`
    2019-11-15T15:32:45.191239+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
    2019-11-15T15:32:45.171631+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
    2019-11-15T15:32:45.136551+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/bin/env: ‘ruby\r’: No such file or directory
    2019-11-15T21:09:12.453945+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
    2019-11-15T21:09:17.586328+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 32126 -e production`
    2019-11-15T21:09:19.654985+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
    2019-11-15T21:09:19.640167+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
    2019-11-15T21:09:19.589960+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/bin/env: ‘ruby\r’: No such file or directory
    2019-11-17T02:02:40.834466+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=obscure-beyond-78036.herokuapp.com request_id=27b9775c-9011-4343-b386-bc8575b3b574 fwd="73.244.194.180" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Comment: Does this question help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29073826/env-ruby-r-no-such-file-or-directory

Comment: @Chiperific I tried that no unfortunately it does not.

Comment: I can't tell from your question, does the app run successfully on localhost?

Comment: What about re-configuring Git as suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52316594/heroku-usr-bin-env-ruby-exe-r-no-such-file-or-directory-problem

Comment: @Chiperific the app runs successfully on localhost tried reconfiguring it gives the same issue.

Comment: Are you developing on a Mac or Windows machine?

Comment: @Chiperific Windows 10

Comment: How did you solve the issue @Sk1993?

Answer (score 0):

I'd put money on the fact you have an invisible `/r` in one of your files.

Check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29074011/1880203

Open up every file in `./bin/` and make sure no spaces or funky characters are after the magic comment that should be in the top of every file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
```

Comment: No spaces or funky characters are present in each file under `./bin/` after the magic comment.